# React Native tutorial / Reference Project (demo)

Tags: react-native

Any Tutorial better for learning responsiveness in react Native.
Or any demo project for reference ?

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please google your question at first step!

Anyway, **[Flexbox](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html):**

> A component can specify the layout of its children using the flexbox algorithm. Flexbox is designed to provide a consistent layout on different screen sizes.